# Macro that loops and find 2 text strings then sum offset values at EXCEL worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, sumifs

it's my first post here, I'm stuck with a macro to find two text strings Ex. Cars and Boats then sums everything between at column C, rinse and repeat (loop for next coincidence) on the same sheet.

Original.

```
A           B      C
CARS        1
ANYTHING    3 
ANYTHING    2 
BOATS       8
```

Result.

```
A              B      C
CARS           1 ---> 1   
ANYTHING       3 ---> 3
ANYTHING       2 ---> 2
BOATS          8 ---> 8
SUM                  14 <--Calculated/sum
TAX               0.035 <--Fixed
TOTAL           SUM*TAX <--Calculated
```

And repeat for next pair of coincidences, I have struggled for some days now using both recorded macros and shared knowledge, but anything seems to work, I hope someone could shed some light over my issue, i'll deeply apreciate it.

Comment: Not sure about the 'rinse and repeat' part, but you need a function that sums a range between 2 row numbers - easy. You need a function that finds what row numbers some text lies on(probably with a startSearchFromRow parameter) - fairly easy. Show some code, and we'll help

Comment: Well, i can show how i worked it with formulas, i don't know how to code on vba, neither how to aproach to it, i only have basic programing knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you would need VBA for this. Simple worksheet formulas are more than enough.

```
'sum in B5
=SUM(INDEX(B:B, MATCH("cars", A:A, 0)):INDEX(B:B, MATCH("boats", A:A, 0)))
'total in B7
=B5*SUM(1, B6)
```

Comment: It's because i want to automate the process the easiest way possible for other people to use it, i already managed it with formuls, but i have never worked with macros in excel.